# Necessary to add a DNS entry for a internal URL in AAM?

Tags: alternate-access-mapping, dns

Can I add an internal URL for a web application without any DNS or HOST entry?

I know it is required for a public URL in case of extending.

Answer (score 2):

SharePoint doesn't care if the URLs for web applications have a DNS/HOST entry except if, you specify that it should access that URL in crawling or ...

But a URL without a DNS/HOST entry somewhere doesn't give you anything as you won't be able to use it for anything.

When you request a URL in the browser (or a program) then the network stack needs to figure out the IP address of the machine hosting the service behind that URL, that's what then DNS/HOST entry gives you. If the network stack doesn't know the IP address then it can't send any requests.

Comment: Thanks Per, 
I got what you are saying, I think i understand the roles of DNS/HOST ,but is it possible to access a site by another internal URL without DNS entry? Did u try anywhere I am just curious about it. soon i am gonna try it on a test envirnoment.